# Getting error on applying UDID as "Please enter a valid UDID"

Tags: ios, udid

Even though I've entered a new valid `UDID` to my developer's account, I'm getting an error `"Please enter a valid UDID"` so I can't proceed from there. Here I've enclose the image.

[image]

Comment: I assume because of your rep that you will need to post the picture on another site.  Until then all anyone can say is "double check the UDID"

Comment: Double check name - UUID ( be sure copy from xCode project)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific non-reproducable error that is likely to be typographic that is not related to programming.

Comment: This might be because your UDID has some missing characters. Your UDID should be 40 characters.

Comment: It would help if the box that contained the UDID (should have just used UUID like everyone else...) was actually big enough to fit the entire identifier. About 10 character were hidden and the box doesn't scroll. Thanks Apple!

Comment: Ensure it is actually the UDID and not the UUID that you're pasting in, as the names look similar but they're different codes.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're getting the wrong number for the UDID. My process for doing this is to:

1. Connect the phone I want to add to my Mac while I have Xcode running.
2. Agree on the phone I can trust this computer and put in my passcode to verify that.
3. Open up "Devices and Simulators" window in Xcode from the Window menu.
4. Copy the number with the label "Identifier" and use that in the Apple developer account portal.

If you have a paired Apple Watch, it'll show on the same Devices screen in Xcode as the phone it's paired with in the section just below the header.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure the device name matches.

Comment: Also please explain why.

Comment: There is no technical reason whatsoever for the device name to match anything. That is a name *you* give to the device, so that it's recognizable for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is specific format for uuid, make sure you don't miss hyphen ("-")
Sample  UUID for iphones :

12345678-1234567891234567

Comment: Not necessarily; a quick glance at the valid identifiers in my account reveals different patterns. Besides, there is no guarantee that the ID has a specific pattern; all that we can expect is that it's an alphanumeric string.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your uuid `00008030001059D93E2BC04R`

add `-` after 8th character **ex.**  `00008030-001059D93E2BC04R`